# Is there a future in MySQL that limits the user based on column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have designed a CRM system with multiple clients level. Each table of my database has a column called "client_id" some people have access to some client_id's but not others. I am able to restrict this data that a user can see by simply adding a where clause "WHERE client_Id IN(1,2,3)"

I was wondering if there is a way for this restriction to be done at the database level or if there is a middle man software that help me with this.

This will give me an additional layer of security to who can see what. So if a hacker was able to changed 1,2,3 to 1,2,3, 4, 5 then the second level will prevent him from viewing data that belongs to client_id 4, 5.

Or if I want to give a user access to the database using MySQL workbench, is it possible that he can be restricted from seeing data that belong to other clients?

Is this possible? I use MySQL for a database but not sure if this is something that even exists in SQL regardless of the server type.

Comment: Not really.  The database has security for, well, database objects with database users.  It doesn't identify your application's users or record-level application objects.  That's business logic for the application to handle.

Comment: SQL in general doesn't mean you have to tag MS SQL Server. Either just sql or perhaps also ansi-sql.

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will have to give specifics for MySQL, but in some DBMSs you can grant access to views. Here is an example using Mimer SQL. First the user dbtek0 creates a table and a view based on that table, and grants access to everyone to read the view, but not the table.

```
SQL> create table oranges (a integer, b integer, c integer);
SQL> insert into oranges (a, b, c) values (1, 2, 3);
SQL> insert into oranges (a, b, c) values (2, 2, 3);
SQL> insert into oranges (a, b, c) values (3, 2, 3);
SQL> select * from oranges;
          A           B           C
=========== =========== ===========
          1           2           3
          2           2           3
          3           2           3

                  3 rows found

SQL> create view someoranges as select a, b from apelsin where a > 1;
SQL> select * from someoranges;
          A           B
=========== ===========
          2           2
          3           2

                  2 rows found

SQL> grant select on someoranges to public;
```

And then, as another user:

```
SQL> select * from dbtek0.oranges;

1: select * from dbtek0.oranges
   ^
Mimer SQL error -12200 in function PREPARE
         Table DBTEK0.ORANGES not found, table does not exist or no access
         privilege

SQL> select * from dbtek0.someoranges;
          A           B
=========== ===========
          2           2
          3           2

                  2 rows found
```

Comment: You can grant permission on views in mysql to a user on a specific database and table(view) by executing "grant show view on database.tablename to user@host". problem is OP will have to create a view for each client and a user for each one. That can be tedious, especially if clients are being added on a daily basis.

Comment: @BK435: Agreed. Views and other parts of the schema should seldom change, and a solution where, say, anyone who registers on your web site gets his own view, so you might get many new views every day, is probably Doing It Wrong.

Comment: I had a similar issue with forums being accessible on the front end after a process(state) had been completed.  I created a table with the state and forum name in which it is accessible to be queried off before the available forums are presented. However, The data seldom changes for that DB. Unfortunately for OP, clients are suspect to change consistently and I am afraid there is no easy way to do what he is asking.